# How to compare values from different rows in the same table for inclusion in another statement's WHERE clause?

Tags: sql

I am really new to SQL, and want to compare two values from two users: For example, the value for the first user at **field_id=3**, and the value for the second user at **field_id=6**. The table looks as follows:

```
+----------+---------+-------+
| field_id | user_id | value |
+----------+---------+-------+
|        1 |       1 | Name1 |
|        2 |       1 | Man   |
|        3 |       1 | Woman |
|        1 |       2 | Name2 |
|        2 |       2 | Woman |
|        3 |       2 | Man   |
+----------+---------+-------+
```

This check, I'm looking for, needs to become part of the following sql statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT MIN(us.ID) FROM ".$wpdb->base_prefix."users us"
. " JOIN ".$wpdb->base_prefix."bp_xprofile_data bp ON us.ID = bp.user_id"
. " JOIN ". $wpdb->base_prefix . "usermeta um ON um.user_id = us.ID"
. " WHERE um.meta_key = 'last_activity' AND us.ID > $current_id"
. " AND   ?????????? What to insert here to compare?????"
```

The check, whether the value for **field_id=2** and **user_id=1** equals the value of **field_id=3** and **user_id=2**, needs to replace above statement's **?????????? What to insert here to compare?????**.
This query is called from php.

Comment: Can you isolate the SQL part of your question or add additional tags to indicate what other languages you are using?

Comment: Is really hard guess what are you doing. But the best advice. Is easy create the query in SQL instead of PHP? so you can test the result and then convert back to a string.

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The plain comparison could be done like

```
SELECT
  'match' AS result
FROM us_user U1
JOIN us_user U2
  ON U1.value = U2.value
  AND U1.field_id = 2
  AND U1.user_id = 1
  AND U2.field_id = 3
  AND U2.user_id = 2
;
```

The exact 'return value' (I picked **match**, could be **1**) is free for you to choose (and does not really need a column alias - as long as your database is easy about it).

See this in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c38df/2)

This could then be made a subquery to be included into your original statement along

```
... AND EXISTS (suggested-query-goes-here)
```

You will most likely need to synch at least one of the tables in the suggested query to one of the tables in your existing statement. But which exactly, I'm not able to tell from the information provided so far.

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail. In particular feel free to extend the Fiddle with structure and sample data for the other tables involved in order to set the full picture straight.